# Hover sobre um elemento que fará efeito em outro

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
.tratoresList h3{
    font-family: "opensans-light-webfont";
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #000;
    width: 210px;
    text-align: center;
}
.tratoresList strong{
    font-family: "opensans-extrabold-webfont";
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #000;
    width: 210px;
}
.tratoresList strong, .tratoresList h3:hover{
    font-family: "opensans-extrabold-webfont";
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #a80000;
    width: 210px;
}
```

Quando eu passar o mouse dentro do `h3` ele tem que fazer o **hover** também no `strong` e vice-versa.

O que eu fiz errado?

Answer (score 4):

Não é assim que o seletor `,` funciona: ele faz duas seleções independentes e aplica o estilo a ambas. No caso, ele aplicará tanto ao `.tratoresList strong` (sobrescrevendo a regra anterior) quanto ao `.tratoresList h3:hover`.

Fazer com que o *hover* sobre um elemento afete um elemento diferente é um pouquinho complicado usando apenas CSS (e sua simetria - "e vice-versa" - piora as coisas ainda mais). Em algumas situações há uma solução relativamente simples, como no caso de fazer *hover* em um elemento e [afetar somente os outros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12418702/520779), ou quando o elemento afetado é [um irmão que sucede o primeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7832603/520779). Mas não conheço nenhuma maneira de fazer o que você quer usando CSS2 ou mesmo CSS3.

Futuramente, no CSS4, deverá ser possível fazer isso usando [`:has`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#relational) - verifica-se a presença de um filho ou descendente mas se seleciona mesmo o ancestral. Não tenho certeza como é o funcionamento exato (uma vez que nem mesmo o CSS3 está 100% disponível, e CSS4 ainda está em rascunho e pode sofrer alterações até ser "lançado") mas diz-se que ele será semelhante ao que é feito hoje no jQuery:

```
.tratoresList:has(strong:hover, h3:hover) strong,
.tratoresList:has(strong:hover, h3:hover) h3 {
    font-family: "opensans-extrabold-webfont";
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #a80000;
    width: 210px;
}
```

Ou seja, "aplique este estilo ao `strong` ou `h3`, que é filho de um `.tratoresList` que possui um descendente `strong:hover` ou um `h3:hover`".

Reiterando, não tenho certeza de que é exatamente assim que funcionará, e de qualquer forma nenhum *browser* atual dá suporte à regra acima. Para fazer o que você quer, de modo geral, só com JavaScript mesmo. Entretanto, *pode ser* que no seu caso específico exista uma solução só com as ferramentas atuais, então se postar seu código HTML podemos ver se é ou não possível fazer o que você quer (eu duvido, dada a simetria, mas sempre há esperança).

Comment: +1.  Provavelmente se ele puser o código vai dar pra ver se tem como arrastar o strong pra dentro do "guarda chuva" do h3, ou ao menos passar o _hover_ pro container.

Comment: Verdade. Mas se o efeito desejado for [algo desse tipo](http://jsfiddle.net/w692yvbg/) acho bastante improvável que se possa fazer somente via CSS... :(

Comment: @mgibsonbr sua resposta foi muito cara, vou conseguir testar apenas mais tarde. Porém, compreendi seu exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entedi bem, o `H3` é irmão do `STRONG`, então é perfeitamente possível fazer apenas com `CSS`. Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```css
.tratoresList h3{
    font-family: "opensans-light-webfont";
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #000;
    width: 210px;
    text-align: center;
}
.tratoresList strong{
    font-family: "opensans-extrabold-webfont";
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #000;
    width: 210px;
}
.tratoresList h3:hover + p > strong {
    font-family: "opensans-extrabold-webfont";
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #a80000;
    width: 210px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="tratoresList">
        <h3>A</h3>
        <p>Blá <strong>blá</strong> blá</p>
    </li>
    <li class="tratoresList">
        <h3>B</h3>
        <p>Blá <strong>blá</strong> blá</p>
    </li>
    <li class="tratoresList">
        <h3>C</h3>
        <p>Blá <strong>blá</strong> blá</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Só para entender o `.tratoresList h3:hover + p > strong`, sempre que o mouse estiver sobre o elemento `H3` (que estiver dentro de um elemento com classe 'tratoresList'), ele aplicará o efeito à todo o `STRONG` que estiver dentro do seu elemento irmão `P`.

Comment: Na realidade o AP não especificou como é seu HTML, esse aí eu inventei da minha cabeça pra exemplificar... Do contrário, sua sugestão seria boa, exceto pela parte do "vice-versa": nem o seletor `+` nem o `~` encontram elementos **atrás** daquele sendo selecionado. Ou seja, não dá para ao passar o mouse sobre o `strong` se aplicar um estilo no `h3` usando esses seletores. :(

Comment: Na verdade eu subentendi que fosse essa a estrutura com base no CSS que o @Felipe Stoker postou. Daria pra ter certeza se entre os elementos, no css, houvesse um sinal de maior (>) indicando que o elemento `H3` é exatamente o primeiro elemento filho de `tratoresList `. Quanto ao vice-versa, infelizmente não há como fazer apenas com `CSS` mesmo =(. Olhando agora com calma, notei que na pergunta ele questiona o vice-versa.